# Caching and manipulating a reference type in C#

Tags: c#, caching

I usually manage my application cache this way.

```c#
public static T GetGenericCachedT<T>(string cacheKey, object locker, Func<T> methodToCall, 
CacheFileEnum cacheFileEnum, int durationMinutes = 60)
{
    object o = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey];

    if (o == null)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            o = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey];
            if (o == null)
            {
                o = methodToCall();

                // Get the full path for the physical file linked to this cache
                string cacheFile = GetCacheFile(cacheFileEnum); 
                CacheDependency d = new CacheDependency(cacheFile);
                // Put in cache
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
                    cacheKey, 
                    o, 
                    d, 
                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(durationMinutes), 
                    Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
        }
    }
    return (T)o;
}
```

And this is an example for a caller

```c#
int i = GetGenericCachedT<int>("ItemsNumber", _CacheLockerItemsNumber, func, CacheFileEnum.Items, 120);
```

Everything works well but it works so well that I'm starting to ask myself what happens if I use the cache for not immutable objects.
For example what happens if I'm using it with a ref type?

```c#
var stringList = GetGenericCachedT<List<string>>("ListOfStrings", _CacheLockerListOfStrings, func, CacheFileEnum.List, 120);
```

Once retrieved, the caller can enumerate stringList or it can add a new member to it or remove an old one. But these operations are outside the lock scope so I risk to have concurrency issues or an inconsistent object.

What's the solution here?
Can I use the same locker I created for the cache retrieval (_CacheLockerListOfStrings) to protect the object manipulation too? Do I risk having concurrent locks? Or performance fall?
Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Whenever you have data that may be shared between threads you need some form of protection, with exception to read-only data. Otherwise you need locks or some other kind of synchronization.